# Edit ckeditor toolbar button

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I added `ckeditor` using this syntax `<script src="https://nightly.ckeditor.com/full/ckeditor.js"></script>`. My `ckeditor` editor toolbar looks like below.

[image]

I would like to add new functionalities to an existing icon.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this CKEditor version CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.3.2/super-build/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

for reference :- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/quick-start.html#using-the-ckeditor-5-superbuild

Answer (score 1):

Let me know the tech stack you are using,

**For plain Javascript** :

```
<script>
  editor = CKEDITOR.replace("container");
  editor.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", {
    exec: function (edt) {
      alert(edt.getData());
    },
  });
  editor.ui.addButton("SuperButton", {
    label: "Click me",
    command: "mySimpleCommand",
    toolbar: "insert",
    icon: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Clock.png",
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Check the clock icon in the toolbar option besides `planet icon`.

Check the codesandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-carlos-qh0kvt?file=/index.html:247-687)

**For frameworks like React.js :**

Try to add as a plugin like this,

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add("timestamp", {
  init: function (editor) {
    editor.addCommand("insertTimestamp", {
      exec: function (editor) {
        var now = new Date();
        editor.insertHtml(now.toString());
      },
    });
    editor.ui.addButton("Timestamp", {
      label: "Insert Timestamp",
      command: "insertTimestamp",
      toolbar: "insert",
      icon: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/24x24-free-pixel-icons/24/Clock.png",
    });
  },
});
```

[image]

Check the `clock icon` in the toolbar option besides `smiley icon`.
You can add the functionality to be performed in the `exec` function

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Hetal N. Where should I place this code ?

Comment: Try to add this code where you are creating the editor object and defining the other tool based options and other config changes.

Comment: @abuabu If this answer helped you with your problem then please accept this solution as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Hetal N. Could you please say about exact place ?

Comment: In which framework you are adding CKEditor ? I have added this answer considering tech stack as React.js

Comment: I have updated my answer and also added the demo link for more detailed code, Please check